# Dynamic circleRadius in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

In my application I have following layout which uses the new [circular positioning](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html#CircularPositioning) property of its inner `ConstraintLayout`. I think it is pretty good because it does not use fixed dp values for any view size except the `circleRadius`.

And exactly that is my problem: My `circleRadius` should also be dynamic but accordingly to the documentation it only takes dimensions. So I need is a dimension relative to the `constraintCircle` size. Is that possible?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.cilenco.ui.activities.OnboardingActivity"
    tools:theme="@style/AppTheme.Onboarding">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/dividor" />

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/spacing_normal"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/spacing_normal"
        android:layout_above="@id/dividor">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
            android:cropToPadding="true"
            android:paddingLeft="72dp"
            android:paddingRight="72dp"
            android:paddingBottom="72dp"
            android:paddingTop="60dp"
            android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:visibility="visible"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_left"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.20"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="@dimen/spacing_normal"
            app:layout_constraintCircle="@id/icon"
            app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="160dp"
            app:layout_constraintCircleAngle="250" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_bottom_left"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.20"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="@dimen/spacing_normal"
            app:layout_constraintCircle="@id/icon"
            app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="165dp"
            app:layout_constraintCircleAngle="205" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_bottom_right"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.20"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="@dimen/spacing_normal"
            app:layout_constraintCircle="@id/icon"
            app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="165dp"
            app:layout_constraintCircleAngle="155" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_right"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.20"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="@dimen/spacing_normal"
            app:layout_constraintCircle="@id/icon"
            app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="160dp"
            app:layout_constraintCircleAngle="110" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/dividor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:alpha="0.4"
        android:background="@color/color_primary_dark"
        android:layout_above="@id/tabDots" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabDots"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/color_primary"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
        app:tabGravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/skip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/skip"
        android:padding="@dimen/spacing_normal"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/next"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackground" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/next"
        android:padding="@dimen/spacing_normal"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackground" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Note that this layout is only used in my onboarding screen so it only has to work in portrait mode. Do you have any ideas how to solve this problem or would you recommend a complete other layout without `ConstraintLayout`? If so how would you design the circle property?

If you also have other ideas how to optimize this layout please let me know. I'm not really good at designing responsive layout that works on all screens...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest that you abandon circular positioning for this particular layout but stick with `ConstraintLayout`. Here is a way to make it work for you by constraining the views that are positioned in a circle around the center icon to the edges of the icon's `ImageView` and using bias. As the device scales, so will the layout and the icons will keep their relative placement.

Here is how the two layouts look on two different devices:

[image]

[image]

I have simplified the layout for this demo by removing the `RelativeLayout` and `ViewPager`. The concept will still work with these reintroduced.

**XML Layout**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/dividor"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#d7d1d1"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/spacing_normal"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/spacing_normal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:paddingBottom="72dp"
        android:paddingLeft="72dp"
        android:paddingRight="72dp"
        android:paddingTop="60dp"
        android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.12"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
        tools:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon_left"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/spacing_normal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/icon_bottom_left"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/icon"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/icon"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.20"
        tools:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon_bottom_left"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/spacing_normal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/icon"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/icon"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.28"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/icon"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.20"
        tools:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon_bottom_right"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/spacing_normal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/icon_bottom_left"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/icon"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.73"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/icon"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.20"
        tools:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon_right"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/spacing_normal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/icon_left"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/icon"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/icon"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.20"
        tools:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```