# ConstraintLayout radius is not responsive

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

- I am using [Circular positioning](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html#CircularPositioning) and I want to avoid using a fixed size value for the radius so that my layout will be responsive to all screen sizes.
- What I have now is `app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="100dp"` on `buttonB`, this fixed size wont be responvise to all screen sizes.
- I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49232415/dynamic-circleradius-in-constraintlayout) but I want to know how to make (if possible) the radius dymanic instead of any workarounds to achieve the desired result.

**I am using this layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonA"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
     android:text="A"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonB"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonA"
    app:layout_constraintCircle="@+id/buttonA"
    app:layout_constraintCircleAngle="40"
    app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="100dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/buttonA"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/buttonA"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/buttonA"
    android:text="B" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**That looks like this:**

[image]

---

In addition, I have checked the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html#CircularPositioning) and it contains fixed sizes values as well, as you can see:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`SDP`**](https://github.com/intuit/sdp)

> An android SDK that provides a new size unit - sdp (scalable dp). This
>   size unit scales with the screen size. It can help Android developers
>   with supporting multiple screens.

Example

```
app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="@dimen/_85sdp"
```

Comment: Looks promising, I will check this answer soon

Answer (score 0):

You need to set int value for  width and height then it will work

Comment: That a very broad answer, can you elaborate? Because  `android:layout_width="800dp"` is int value but it wont be responsive at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the requested radius on run-time and change the radius programmatically by setting the `ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams` [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.html#circleRadius)