# How to set button margins while using Circular positioning from ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am using Circular Positioning from ConstraintLayout to organize buttons in circle:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


         <Button
            android:id="@+id/center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/one"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintCircle="@id/center"
            app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="100dp"
            app:layout_constraintCircleAngle="51"
            android:text="one"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/two"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintCircle="@id/center"
            app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="100dp"
            app:layout_constraintCircleAngle="103"
            android:text="two"/>

       ...

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

However, if I have seven buttons organized in circle, buttons at 0 and 180 degrees are too close to other buttons, so  I want to set top and bottom margin to those buttons. Also, I want to set margins between some buttons, i.e. left or right margin.

For example, I wonder if is it possible to programatically set margins to ***button SEVEN*** and also between **button four and three**, without the need of changing ***layout_constraintCircleRadius*** value?

Please check this screenshot example to get better understanding:
[buttons in circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xZTq.png)

[Output will be something like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1Dln.png)

Comment: I think Margin will not work because all your Buttons are Wrap and The circular Radius is Fixed .. You can increase radius to provide Gap between items .. Or you can change the angle .. Can you show the expected Output Image ?

Comment: Yeah, but I want the radius to be fixed. I have edited the question with provided Output sample.

Comment: If you want to keep fix radius so that it can form a Circle . Then You should increase it for all .. The Problem Here if width of Button .. And wrap Button 3 and 4 inside a another layout with margin and Set circle Constraints to this layout .. It will work i think ..

Comment: There is not a lot of flexibility in circular positioning. I answered a similar question a while back that may help you. Take a look at [_Dynamic circleRadius in ConstraintLayout_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49256510/6287910).